# What search algorithm should I use if I need to find a value OR the next highest?

Tags: python, list, search, binary-search

I will have an ordered list of Transaction ID's like this:

```
41025745
41025741
41025740
41025739
41025738
41025735
41025721
41025719
41025718
41025717
41025699
41025683
41025682
41025681
```

Anywhere from 10-1000 depending on how many I figure out I want to grab at a time based on API calls.

Say I want to find Transaction ID 41025735 (in the list) I could just use binary search to find it but if I want to find 41025736 (not in the list) I would return 41025738, the next highest value. What should I use? A modified Binary Search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) supports this directly but it requires that the input be in ascending order:

```
>>> from bisect import bisect_left

>>> data = '''\
41025745 41025741 41025740
41025739 41025738 41025735 41025721
41025719 41025718 41025717 41025699
41025683 41025682 41025681'''

>>> trans_ids = sorted(s.split())
>>> def find_ge(a, x):
        'Find leftmost item greater than or equal to x'
        i = bisect_left(a, x)
        if i != len(a):
            return a[i]
        raise ValueError

>>> find_ge(trans_ids, '41025736')
'41025738'
```

Comment: What is it called in the bisect module? And what would be the quickest way to flip the list from descending to ascending?

Comment: Thanks I literraly just found that online by looking at the documentation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Since your list is already sorted from largest to smallest, you do not need to sort. Here is an alternative that does not require presorting the list:

```
>>> data
['41025745', '41025741', '41025740', '41025739', '41025738', '41025735', '41025721', '41025719', '41025718', '41025717', '41025699', '41025683', '41025682', '41025681']
>>> def find_ge(li, item):
...     for e in reversed(li):
...         if e>=item:
...             return e
...      
...     raise ValueError  
>>> find_ge(data, '41025736')
'41025738'
>>> find_ge(data, '41025735')
'41025735'
```